# Does every graph have an algebraic form?

Tags: graphing-functions, plane-curves

Let's say I take a pencil and start drawing a curve on $xy$ plane. The curve is continuous and for each value of $x$ there is only one corresponding value of $y$.

So question that interests me is - for any curve I draw, is there a polynomial that describes that curve?

Comment: Yes, for each such line there would be a polynomial of the form $ax+b$ that describes it.

Comment: @Workaholic From his description I'm pretty sure when he said "line" he meant "curve"...

Comment: Did you mean a straight line or a more general curve?

Comment: I mean totally random line, like a heartbeat or something like this

Comment: That "line" is actually a _curved_ line, right? If so you really shouldn't call it a line - call it a curve instead. Anyway: No, there need not be a polynomial that describes the curve exactly. But there _are_ polynomials that _approximately_ describe the curve, as close as you want.

Comment: Yes it is a curve,I am sorry, but how to prove this ?

Comment: How to prove that is a long story, which probably you're not really ready for. Look for the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem if you really want to know.

Comment: Thank you for your answers David, Workaholic.

Answer (score 2):

If you meant a line, then yes, for each line you draw satisfying the property you mentioned there would be a polynomial of the form $ax+b$ that describes it.

And if you meant a general curve, then consider the following: Draw a continuous curve on $[0,1]$ satisfying $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and such that this curve has an additional root in some point $c\in(0,1)$. Repeat this process with all intervals of the form $[n,n+1]$, i.e. make it periodic. This graph is continuous and has infinitely many roots, but no polynomial can have that much roots.

---

What if one adds the assumption that the curve has only finitely many roots? Well draw a random continuous shape on a finite interval such that it crosses the $x$-axis in one instance, then at the 'sides' of this curve on this interval, draw two lines parallel to the $x$-axis so as to make it continuous over $\mathbb{R}$. Now a basic property of polynomials p with degree $n\gt0$ is that $\lim\limits_{|x|\to\infty}p(x)=\pm\infty$. Yet in this case the limits at $\pm\infty$ will be real numbers contradicting that property.

---

What if one adds  the assumption that the curve goes to $\pm\infty$ at $\pm\infty$? Well, a polynomial $p$ can be written as $p(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_kx^k$ (and $p(0)=a_0$), thus $p''(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2}b_kx^k$. This last polynomial will have finitely many roots, thus finitely many changes in its sign. So $p$ will have finitely many changes in its convexity (at one interval it will be convex upward, and in another convex downward). And as we did previously, we can draw a curve such that it is

1. continuous,
2. has finitely many roots,
3. goes to $\pm\infty$ at $\pm\infty$,
4. changes its convexity infinitely often.

And hence it can't be represented by a polynomial because of the fourth property.

---

Polynomials are differentiable everywhere. You may pick up any continuous function that isn't differentiable at one or more points (e.g. $x\mapsto|x|$ isn't differentiable at $x=0$) and you get such curve.

---

These type of constructions generally rely on making a curve that violates a property of polynomials. But to be much more general, your question boils down to whether any continuous function is a polynomial, and the answer is that only a tiny set of continuous functions are a polynomial.

Comment: What if i add assumption that curve has finite number of roots?

Comment: @Ilovemath See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively you're asking "Is every continuous function (on some interval of real numbers) a polynomial?" The answer is a resounding "No", but in a sense that's difficult to make precise in a non-technical way. Loosely, polynomials represent a Very Thin Subset of the space of all continuous functions.

There are plenty of familiar functions that are not polynomials, such as quotients of polynomials having no common non-constant factor, the natural exponential function, the circular (trig) functions. Further, if you add any such function to a polynomial, you get another non-polynomial. (Why?) That already starts to suggest how "rare" polynomials are even among the functions familiar from (pre-)calculus.

As David Ullrich notes, every continuous function *is* approximated as closely as you like on a closed, bounded interval, in the sense that if you draw your continuous curve with a pencil whose lead has positive diameter (but diameter as small as you like), then over every closed, bounded interval, there is a polynomial whose graph lies within the region covered by your pencil. This isn't easy to prove, but requires nothing beyond undergraduate-level analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several methods how to get this polynomial like Lagranges polynomial https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial or newtons polynomial https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial which is faster method.

Comment: Interpolating polynomials generally do not give good approximations except at the interpolated points...